# SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)'))

Tags: python, websocket, ws-client, sslerrorhandler

def ws_run():
global ws
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url,on_open=on_open,on_message=on_message,on_error=on_error,on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation, i found solution myself

`self.ws.run_forever(sslopt={"cert_reqs": ssl.CERT_NONE})`